# The probability distribution of a discrete random variable. Check My work.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

The probability distribution of a discrete random variable  is given below:

Value $x$ of $X$

-3

-2

-1

0

1

$P(X=x)$
0.24

0.15

0.23

0.11

0.27

Let $Fx$ be the cumulative distribution function of X. Compute the following

$Fx(-1)=$

$ Fx(-2)-Fx(-3)=$

$ Fx(-9/4)=$

My answer

## $Fx(-1)=0.23$

## $Fx(-2)-Fx(-3)=0.15-0.24=-0.09

Is it correct?

Comment: The same question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2724963/