# Probability distribution of a discrete random variable-

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability distribution of a discrete random variable is given below:

Value x of X

-3

-2

-1

0

1

P(X=x)

0.24

0.15

0.23

0.11

0.27

Let Fx be the cumulative distribution function of X.

Compute the following

Fx(−1)=

Fx(−2)−Fx(−3)=

Fx(−9/4)=

My answer Fx(−1)=0.23

$Fx(-2)-Fx(-3)=0.15-0.24=-0.09

Is it correct?

Comment: {lease format with JaX for more enthusiastic participation.

Comment: The same question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2724925/

Comment: No, it is not correct. $F_x(-2)-F_x(-3)\neq -0.09$